# How to Include and Use GSON library in Netbeans project

Tags: import, gson, netbeans-8

I am trying to import gson into my project so as to convert my data to json format.I am writing my code on NetBeans .I have imported the gson-2.2.4 jar to my library folder but stil it is not working.

Comment: It is not clear what `imported the gson-2.2.4 jar` or `it is still not working` means. To add a jar to the default Ant-based java project, right-click the `Libraries` node under your project and select `Add Jar/Folder ...`.   BTW: Why use gson-2.2.4 when 2.5 is the latest?

Comment: why is not working?? what is the error you are getting??